# NodeJS package dependencies don't update when I install everything

Tags: node.js

When I run `npm install --save [module_name]`.
My package.json dependencies don't update ,why?

Comment: what are the contents of pkg.json?

Comment: What is the output of `npm install --save [module_name] && cat package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you want to update your dependencies in your package.json? If you're looking to update or uninstall, the following may be of some use.

- update: `npm update -S [module_name]`
- remove: `npm uninstall -S [module_name]`